# Package Quicklook plugins for Appstore

Tags: macos, app-store, quicklook

I have a bunch of `Quicklook` plugins and I would like to make them available through the AppStore. As of now, I only have experience with the IOS store and not the Mac store. Is there some kind of standard tutorial on how to create a package that after AppStore download unwraps itself and installs all plugins into the right `Library/Quicklook` folder automatically? We are about to create a AppStore account for OSX (not IOS).

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to install it. You can store a Quick Look generator in an application bundle (in `MyApp.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/`).

Details in the [Quick Look Programming Guide > Installing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Articles/QLArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005020-CH4-SW4)

Comment: @El Dude  did this answer help you? if yes, would you like to accept it?